# Why do I get 'Error: Invalid hook call' when I am calling inside a function?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I am getting the **'Error: Invalid hook call'** when I use a hook on my Next.js app. I can't figure out why I am getting this error as I thought it was being called inside a function component?

```
Server Error
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Source
pages/index.js (16:44) @ getStaticProps
  14 | 
  15 | export const getStaticProps = async () => {
> 16 |   const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(LINGO_QUERY);
     |                                            ^
  17 | 
  18 |   return {
  19 |     props: {
```

Check out my codesandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/empty-sea-hjunv

Comment: Its not a function component, you can't use hook there, I guess you just should call fetch.

Comment: I'm using Apollo so I shouldn't need to use fetch?

Comment: You use apollo hooks so you can only use them in function components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use hook outside react component.

Then, in nextjs, `getStaticProps` is a function used in server side context, and is pre-render at build time.

https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my sandbox. I'm now getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` but I thought I had defined it in the hook?

Comment: You define it but i think his value is null or undefined (because .map is only usable with array). Maybe your query is not working well or you don't have any data to fetch inside graphql

Comment: I've had a look in the GraphQL playground and the results I expected are returned. There's just one term in the database at the moment: `{
  "data": {
    "allTerms": [
      {
        "id": "600456129d8f3455d5631403",
        "term": "accelerator",
        "slug": "accelerator"
      }
    ]
  }
}`

Comment: Ok but you're tried to iterate with .map throught `data`, but is not an array. Look at your GraphQL response. I think you need to use .map with `allTerms` array. 

`data.allTerms.map((...) => { ... })`

Comment: Thanks. That would work but I don't think it populates the page because it needs to wait for the data and therefore returns undefined. Should this be done with await?

Comment: You can try with await but i don't think the component will rerender. However, you can use `useEffect` hook. This will listen on your dataset and rerender the component if it change.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use hook outside component. Your `getStaticProps` is not a component, its a function that you use to return props.

You can read more about it here: https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html#breaking-the-rules-of-hooks

Just use that `useQuery` hook in a component and use it to get some data and render it regularly.

You are probably executing that function somewhere as regular function.

To use hook you need to call it inside a component, and that is a rule because hooks may return some jsx and React made that as mandatory.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated my codesandbox as now I'm getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`. But `data` is defined in the hook, no?

Comment: @Anthony you need to update your codesandbox, it's not working properly. Showing Internal Server Error. you need to add all of dependencies

Comment: I think that's due to my API being run on localhost and I am not sure how to get it running on the sandbox. The query is in the api directory in the sandbox though, and I've tested it locally on the GraphQL playground and it returns the expected results.

Comment: `{
  "data": {
    "allTerms": [
      {
        "id": "600456129d8f3455d5631403",
        "term": "accelerator",
        "slug": "accelerator"
      }
    ]
  }
}`

Comment: Well you need to check at first if it is undefined. Cant use `.map` on the spot. Add ternary `data ? data.map... : null`